# C# getting upper 4 bits of uint32 starting with first significant bit

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, uint32

My need is - have some (in-fact pseudo) random number of `uint32`, i need it's 4 first bits stating with 1st bit, which in not 0, e.g.

> ...000100101 => 1001
>
> 1000...0001 => 1000
>
> ...0001 => 0001
>
> ...0000 => 0000

etc
I understand i have to use something like this

```
uint num = 1157 (some random number)
uint high = num >> offset
```

The problem is - i don't know where the first bit is so i can't use `>>` with constant variable. Can some one explain how to find this `offset`?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there is such bit. What should happen in the case of `0000` or `0010`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first calculate the *highest significant bit (HSB)* and then shift accordingly. You can this like:

```
int hsb = -4;
for(uint cnum = num; cnum != 0; cnum >>= 1, hsb++);
if(hsb < 0) {
    hsb = 0;
}
uint result = num >> hsb;
```

So we first aim to detect the index of the highest set bit (or that index minus four). We do this by incrementing `hsb` and shifting `cnum` (a copy of `num`) to the right, until there are no set bits anymore in `cnum`.

Next we ensure that there is such set bit and that it has at least index four (if not, then nothing is done). The result is the original `num` shifted to the right by that `hsb`.

If I run this on `0x123`, I get `0x9` in the `csharp` interactive shell:

```
csharp> uint num = 0x123;
csharp> int hsb = -4;
csharp> for(uint cnum = num; cnum != 0; cnum >>= 1, hsb++);
csharp> if(hsb < 0) {
      >     hsb = 0;
      > }
csharp> uint result = num >> hsb;
csharp> result
9
```

`0x123` is `0001 0010 0011` in binary. So:

```
0001 0010 0011
   1 001
```

And `1001` is `9`.

Answer (score 2):

Determining the position of the most significant non-zero bit is the same as computing the logarithm with base 2. There are "bit shift tricks" to do that quickly on a modern CPU:

```
int GetLog2Plus1(uint value)
{
    value |= value >> 1;
    value |= value >> 2;
    value |= value >> 4;
    value |= value >> 8;
    value |= value >> 16;
    value -= value >> 1 & 0x55555555;
    value = (value >> 2 & 0x33333333) + (value & 0x33333333);
    value = (value >> 4) + value & 0x0F0F0F0F;
    value += value >> 8;
    value += value >> 16;
    value &= 0x0000003F;
    return (int) value;
}
```

This will return a number from 0 to 32:

```
Value                                      | Log2 + 1
-------------------------------------------+---------
0b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000U |        0
0b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001U |        1
0b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0010U |        2
0b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0011U |        2
0b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0100U |        3
...
0b0111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111U |       31
0b1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000U |       32
0b1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001U |       32
...                                        |
0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111U |       32
```

(Math nitpickers will notice that the logarithm of 0 is undefined. However, I hope the table above demonstrates how that is handled and makes sense for this problem.)

You can then compute the most significant non-zero bits taking into account that you want the 4 least significant bits if the value is less than 8 (where log2 + 1 is < 4):

```
var log2Plus1 = GetLog2Plus1(value);
var bitsToShift = Math.Max(log2Plus1 - 4, 0);
var upper4Bits = value >> bitsToShift;
```